# Upgrade PHP 5.3.1 to 5.3.6 in Mac XAMPP

Tags: php, macos, xampp

I just downloaded Symfony2, and it requires >= PHP 5.3.2, but the latest Mac version of XAMPP only has 5.3.1

Is it possible to swap/upgrade v5.3.1 with 5.3.6 with XAMPP? If so, how?

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6.8, also.

Comment: I don't know if xampp allows you to selectively uninstall a component, but you can always install apache and php and mysql separately if need be.

Comment: You should be able to just replace the interpreter just by overwriting it. Works under linux, I assume it works under mac  too ;)

Answer (score 2):

XAMP [released a BETA](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-beta.html) for Mac that runs PHP 5.4.7

Answer (score 1):

I left MAMP for this reason a couple of years ago, switch to [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) and you'll be happy...

For the differences between them:

### MacPorts

- **Pro**: has a lot of software, you'll find anything you need.
- **Con**: it's slower because it will download and compile any single piece of software. It doesn't use your system libraries, so you need more disk space. On the other side this could be a pro, because you'll never find a library issue (lib x require lib y version z)

### Homebrew

- **Pro**: simpler and faster, and if you do know ruby you can write your own recipe to add missing software. Doesn't need sudo access.
- **Con**: you can encounter issues related to library versions and dependencies, MacPorts has more software than homebrew.

Comment: +1 for MacPorts.  I've had zero problems with MacPorts and it's so easy to add PHP modules as and when you need them.

Answer (score 1):

Just download the installer and install xampp; i had tried that in mac os x it work 100% without any error and lost of data.

Note:-
I had updated my from xampp 1.7.3 to xampp 1.8.3